# In C++, why does declaring a different return type for function definition and declaration change the output of the function?

Tags: c++, compilation, linkage

I have three files as follows:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << add(3, 4) << "\n" << add(3,4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**add.h**

```
double add(int a, int b);
```

**add.cpp**

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

This compiles and the output seems very weird to me:

```
4.6836e-310
0
```

I would never do this in practice but am trying to learn how the linkage editor and compiler work. Firstly, why is the output for the first not 7? Secondly, why does the same function return 0 when called again?

Comment: You're lying to your compiler.  It gets its own back by not doing what you want.  You should `#include "add.h"` in `add.cpp` so you get the cross-checking necessary for the compiler to spot your misstatements.  I'm surprised that your code links — the function defined in `add.cpp` should not be called by the code in `main.cpp`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The return type is not a part of a function signature.

Comment: When my compiler sees both the declaration (in __add.h__) and definition (in __add.cpp__) of `add()`, it aborts with `error: ambiguating new declaration of 'int add(int, int)'` and `note: old declaration 'double add(int, int)'`. Probably not worth figuring out what the compiler ended up doing when you bypassed this. (But if you are still curious, consider the fact that `double` and `int` are probably not the same size, so you probably corrupted your call stack.)

Comment: I'm on x64 Linux which has a register calling convention, the function deposits the result in rax and the caller looks for it in xmm0. (integer and floating return values are passed in different registers, so if the caller tries to retrieve a double, they get random crap) See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions

Comment: Thank you all. I think this is a good lesson to cross-check my header and .cpp files. When I add #include "add.h" in add.cpp, the compiler catches the ambiguous declaration.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Mangling of function names traditionally does not consider their return types.  (If it did, there would be a *different* set of IFNDR programs that run but misbehave.)

Comment: That is the whole point of header file: to make sure every translation unit sees the same declarations.

Comment: @Evg The return type is not part of the function signature, but it is part of the function type ([[dcl.fct]/p8](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#8)) along with the linkage. The compiler can include it in the mangled name that the linker uses (MSVC does this) to issue a diagnostic but is not required to.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Good point, thanks.